# Sessão AppSettings não é lida quando executada em Container Docker

Tags: asp.net-core, docker

Referente a leitura do AppSettings pelo Docker-Compose.
Quando eu rodo através do docker-compose, eu não consigo carregar o appsettings do arquivo.

[image: Linha em que estoura o object reference]

Por isso, **somente quando executo pelo docker-compose ele não encontra a sessão AppSettings** e recebo um `object reference` na linha 19.

Pude analisar que:

1. O arquivo está dentro do Container.
   [image: Conteúdo do container]
2. O Ambiente foi setado corretamente pelo docker-compose
   [image: Environment está para Production]
3. Esse erro **só acontece quando eu executo via command-line o docker-compose**. Ou seja, iniciando a aplicação pelo visual studio, ele lê corretamente o appsettings.
   Inclusive eu já até mesmo executei um publish e localmente startei com sucesso através da .dll publicada.
4. Configuração desejada no appsettings.Production.json *(eu até coloquei em todos para ver se o problema era algo com environment, mas parece ser mesmo sobre a leitura da AppSettings no arquivo)*.
   [image: Appsettings (dados fictícios)]

Comment: acesse o container e verifique os paths dos arquivos. Lembre-se que se estiver a usar containers linux, os paths são *case sensitive*, para evitar problemas pode usar tudo minúsculo. Coloque logs na app tbm para validar se carregou corretamente os arquivos

Comment: Eu copio tudo para uma pasta **/app**, o conteúdo dessa é o item 2 que marquei. Sobre ser case sensitive, eu tento ler a sessão **"AppSettings"** tal como está no arquivo, e o environment eu defino como **- ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production**, acho que são os pontos em que isso atrapalharia, não me vem outro em mente. O arquivo do compose está com formato LF.

Comment: Realmente, revi com cuidado e era uma chamada do appsettings. Pode publicar como resposta para caso alguém passe por isso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como dito pelo @Ricardo Pontual, o problema era mesmo pelo case sensitive (que é considerado no linux).

Revisei o todo o código e encontrei a diferença numa chamada do appsettings.

```
 var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(hostEnvironment.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile(path: "appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile(path: $"appsettings.{hostEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
```